# Join with flag to not require an associated row in the joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have `table1` which has the following columns:

- `t1_id` (primary key, auto_increment)
- `row_1`
- `row_2`
- `open_1` can be 0 or 1.

I have `table2` which has the following columns:

- `t1_id` (foreign key to `table1.t1_id`)
- `row_1` can be 0 or 1
- some other columns

When the tables are generated, if there are no columns generated for `table2` then `table1.open_1` = 1.

So if open_1 is 1, there are no rows with the same `t1_id` key in `table2`, otherwise there are 1 or more rows in `table2` with the same `t1_id`.

I want to retrieve `table1.row_1, table1.row_2` where **EITHER** of these is true:

- `open_1` is 1, or
- `table2.row_1` is 1

I've tried this:

```
SELECT table1.row_1, table1.row_2 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
    ON table1.t1_id = table2.t1_id
WHERE table1.open_1 = 1
    OR table2.row_1 = 1
```

But it doesn't return results where `open_1` is 1.

I think it's because when `open_1` = 1, there are no associated rows in `table2`, so the JOIN clause retrieves no rows.

If I do 2 queries, I can do it easily (first retrieving the rows where open_1 is 1, then retrieving the rows where `table1.t1_id` = `table2.t1_id`), but I want to do it in 1 query.

Can I do this with 1 query?

Data:

> table1:

```
t1_id    row_1    row_2    open_1
1        5        3        1      <---- open_1 = 1, so retrieve this
2        4        7        0
3        6        2        0
4        8        1        0
5        9        7        0
```

> table2:

```
t1_id    row_1    row_2    row_3
2        0        3        4
2        1        2        5     <--- row_1 is 1
2        1        4        2
3        0        3        4
3        1        2        5     <--- row_1 is 1
4        0        4        2
5        0        3        4
```

So in `table1`, `open_1` is 1 for the first row, so I want to retrieve that row, and `open_1` is 0 for rows 2-5, so I want to retrieve those results only if a matching row in `table2` has `row_1` = 1.

So I want to retrieve 3 results:

```
row_1    row_2
5        3
4        7
6        2
```

**My problem is that I can't retrieve the first row (where open_1 = 1) because there are no corresponding rows in the 2nd table. So I want a way to add this row if open_1 = 1, regardless of the JOIN**

Comment: Please keep some data sample with expected result.

Comment: @JERRY I added it

Comment: Why have you called your columns "row_x" ? - recipe for confusion. I see three occurrences of row_1 being a value of 1, why did you only point out two of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **union** clause :

```
select table1.row_1, table1.row_2 
FROM table1 where table1.open_1 = 1
UNION
SELECT table1.row_1, table1.row_2 
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.t1_id = table2.t1_id
WHERE table2.row_1 = 1
```

Comment: Personally I'd go with the left join approach first but this solution may have some merit in performance tuning - I frequently see situations where our DBA rewrites an "where x=y or a = b" query to "where x=y union where a=b" for a performance gain

Comment: It's also a lot easier to understand. I'm a beginner and I knew about left joins but I couldn't get it to work. When I saw this example of a union I understood how to solve it and had it working in about 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use left join

```
  Select  distinct t1.row_1,t1.row_2 from table1  t1
      left join table2 t2 on
     t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id  where t1.open_1=1 or t2.row_1=1
```

Comment: Side note, from the data given I believe this query will return an extra duplicated row not present in the desired result set in the question. The union operator in the currently accepted answer is likely hiding this row

Answer (score 0):

You need a [LEFT JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/outer-join-optimization.html)

```
SELECT table1.row_1, table1.row_2 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.t1_id = table2.t1_id
WHERE table1.open_1 = 1
    OR table2.row_1 = 1
```